# Not able to generate a ReportAnomalyEvent or ReportEventStream using Streaming API

Tags: streaming-api, event-monitoring

We have enabled streaming and storage for various events under event manager. While we are able to get payloads for other event type such as LightningUriEventStream, ListViewEventStream, LoginAsEventStream, LoginEventStream, LogoutEventStream, **we are unable to get data for ReportAnomalyEvent or ReportEventStream**.

According to this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_reportanomalyeventstore.htm, I have created reports, exported them, not save them etc, but it is not populating ReportAnomalyEventStore or ReportEvent objects.

I just want to do one or two activities that would trigger that.

Any tips?

Comment: Does it give you any results when you run SOQL `SELECT Score, UserId, EventDate, Report, SecurityEventData, Summary
FROM ReportAnomalyEventStore`

Comment: Nothing at all @Swetha